# How to run NERDTree manually it it was setup with pathogen?

Tags: gvim

I'd like to install [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) (I'm on 32-bit Win 7, anyway).

And to make vim plugins management easier, [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) needs to be installed first.
So here's the steps:

1. Take [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/autoload/pathogen.vim) and put it on C:\vim\vim73\autoload
2. Make the 'bundle' directory (C:\vim\vimfiles\bundle)
3. Do 'git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git' in the bundle directory
4. Put this line in your .vimrc: execute pathogen#infect()

Of course, every time you run gvim, NERDTree will also run, because it's invoked by pathogen and pathogen is autoloaded. Sometimes I find this to be annoying. So is there any way to make NERDTree to be able to run manually? But I do not want to remove pathogen because with it plugin removal is so easy: just get ride the plugin directory from 'bundle'.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if you can avoid having NERDTree run on start, or are you asking how to start it manually if you've closed it after the first start?

If the latter, you can run NERD tree manually via

```
:NERDTreeToggle
```

which opens the current directory

or

```
:NERDTreeFind
```

Which will open the tree up to the current file.

Handy mappings, so the first is "\" and the second is "|":

```
map \           :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
map \|          :NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

I'm assuming that these bindings will work on Windows, but I don't have a windows box handy to test it.

Comment: What I actually want is being able to load plugins (in this case: NERDTree) via pathogen manually. So it won't run on start, and once I close it I can run it again. :NERDTreeToggle and :NERDTreeFind don't work here, because it was installed via pathogen, and not the standard way of installing plugins (copying files to plugin, ftplugin, doc, etc)